# How to represent graph structures in xml?

Tags: xml, data-structures, graph, xsd

I have structure like :

NodeBrackets - It can have multiple nodebracket
NodeBracket - It consists of nodegroups and nodes.
NodeGroup - Consists of both nodegroups and nodes.
Node- represent individual item.

I have to represent this graph structure in the form of XML. 
Tried to do one like :

```
<nodebrackets />
 <nodebracket>
    <name>Bracket 1</name>    
    <nodeGroups>
      <node>
          <name>Node Group 1</name>
          <type>nodeGroup</type>
          <nodes>
            <node>
                  <name>Node Group 2</name>
                  <type> nodeGroup </type>
                  <nodes>
                      <node>
                        <name>Node 5</name>
                        <type> node </type>
                        </node>
                   </nodes>
            </node>
            <node>
                   <name>Node 1</name>
                   <type> node </type>
            </node>
         </nodes>
     </node>
     <node>
          <name>Node Group 3</name>
          <type> nodeGroup </type>
          <nodes>
             <node>
                   <name>Node 3</name>
                   <type> node </type>
             </node>
             <node>
                   <name>Node 4</name>
                   <type> node </type>
              </node>
          </nodes>
     </node>
   </nodeGroups>
   <nodes>
     <node>
          <name>Node 1</name>
          <type> node </type>
     </node>
     <node>
          <name>Node 4</name> 
          <type> node </type>
     </node>
   </nodes>
  </nodebracket>
</nodebrackets>
```

This structure contains nodes under each node to represent the child nodes (though it is not actually parent-child relation but graph relations)

Questions : Is the above representation correct ?

What are the other ways to represent the graph structures in the form of xml ?

Comment: Using XML makes hierarchical structures to be easily represented. But for generalised graphs you're probably better off just serialising one of the common formats (because there is nothing in XML that will do any better). Eg. if you are representing your graph as a list of connections (the node list being implicit and nodes having no state) then a list of connections could be saved into XML.

Comment: Even if nodes do have state and have to be explicit, you're better off storing a flat list of nodes first, followed by a flat list of connections.

Comment: or use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database

Comment: @Antonio : In the XML

Comment: I saw the title, but you are solving very well-studied task. E.g. http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphML